# How can I get feedback/interaction from the .NET WebBrowser control?

Tags: c#, .net, browser

I am building some kind of eBook reader in C# and have the following problem. Rendering HTML in the WebBrowser control just works fine. However, I want to be able to mark text samples with the mouse. This should be available via a button event or (even better) by click-and-drag directly onto the text. How can I get the feedback of the mouse events in the WebControl (and also the selected text)? Are there any examples around?

In a further step I want toe be able to insert notes as well (maybe by HTML injection)

I tried to get it to work with the WebControl, but had not a lot of success. Maybe some of you know a different approach (Gecko, Webkit?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have DOM of the document loaded, and all you need to mark the samples is to modify the the source using DOM. DOM is, roughly speaking is a tree, that represents html source of WebBrowser control.

See [IHTMLDocument2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752574(v=VS.85).aspx) . It's all not so complicated..

Comment: You can make arbitrary changes (I've done this to update relative links to point to the actual web site when caching the page locally).